# Make DateTime.Now Display European Format Globally on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

I'm running a .NET Core app which contains DateTime.Now.ToString(). When on my PC it displays European date format (dd/mm/yy) but when running on a Linux VM located in the US it displays American date format (mm/dd/yy) despite the timezone on the VM being GMT.

How can I make it display only European date format?

I know I can format it manually inside the program, but is there a way to do this globally on the Linux system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set a culture for all application threads you can use [`CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture?view=netcore-3.0) property, like that

```cs
if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name == "en-US")
{
      culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("...");

      CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
      CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
}
```

You are checking that current culture is `en-US` and update the default culture to any EU specific culture, like `de-DE` or `fr-FR` for example. You can also refer to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture?view=netcore-3.1) for details

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but that'll certainly do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code :

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy")
```

It should work.

For more info: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1